# Div isnt positioned right with css in ie8

Tags: html, css

I have got this div..:

```
    <a href="/"><div id="logoCover" style="position: absolute;width: 341px;height: 100px;z-index: 9999;top: 0px;left: 0px;"></div></a>
```

The problem with the div, is that, it would only show in ie8, if i give it a background  color.
Otherwise the div wont exist, which means the user cant click on it.. why is that behavior common in ie8 and how do I prevent it

**UPDATE:**
This is the element on which I try to place my div:

```
#logo {

    float: left;
    height: 93px;
    }
```

logo is an image

**FULL HTML:**

```
<div id="logo" style="position:relaive;"> 
    <a href="/" style="position: absolute;padding:60px;padding-right: 300px;z-index: 9999;top:-20px;left: 0px;;display:block;" ></a>

      <img src="images/BestCam_logo.png" width="1009px" />
    </div>
```

Comment: Not sure, but perhaps because it doesn't have any value in it? Try adding &nbsp; inside the div?

Comment: notice that some doctypes do not support a `div` element nested in an `a` element.

Comment: i tried to add another div inside.. and character.. you can only press on the character.. i think the div shrinks to the content that it holds

Comment: No, by default the `<a>` tag is an `inline` element, which means it will shrink to it's content.  A `<div>` tag, however, is a `block` element by default, which means that it is supposed to stretch to the full width of its parent container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <div id="logo" style="position:relaive;"> 
        <a href="/" style="position: absolute;padding:60px;padding-right: 300px;z-index: 9999;top:-20px;left: 0px;;display:block;background-image: url('images/emptyImage.png')" ></a>

      <img src="images/BestCam_logo.png" width="1009px" />
    </div>
```

Solved the problem, What I had to do is to use a transparent image, as a background.

Answer (score 2):

`<div>` tags are not supported as content for `<a>` tags inside of standard HTML.  Some browsers try to acommodate for this, but you really can't depend on every browser implementation to handle it the same way.

However, you can make an `<a>` tag a `block` element (it is an `inline` element by default) and move the style from the `<div>` tag to the `<a>` tag.  This would also eliminate the need for the inner `<div>` tag in your example.

`<a href="/" style="display: block; position: absolute;width: 341px;height: 100px;z-index: 9999;top: 0px;left: 0px;"></a>`

Comment: it is a close answer..but had no effect..I am thinking of simply giving it padding instead and see if it works

Comment: You mentioned that you are trying to add it inside an image, that is also an `inline` element.  Perhaps you should post the full HTML that includes your #logo element so we can see exactly how you're trying to lay them out.

Comment: posted it.. it seems that ie doesnt want the div to be above the image, even though I specify a higher z-index

Comment: It may be easiest for you to make BestCam_logo.png the background image for #logo, rather than an element inside of it.  Then just size your div to the appropriate size of the image.  Add this line to `#logo` in your CSS fle: `background-image: url('images/BestCam_logo.png');`.  And remove the `img` tag.

Comment: Hmm..that is a close solution.. I used something else that worked for me..see my solution

Answer (score 0):

try adding display:block or insert a ' '
also, check that your relative div is also rendering right.

hope that helps.

Comment: Both solutions didnt work..but i added some text inside.. you can click on it.. I think ie does so by the content and not by width/height

Comment: it depends on how you render it. once you put a absolute positioning on it, it usually brakes the block structure. Try making it relative maybe or only work via margins/paddings to position it.

See Mike C's answer.

see Mike C's answer.

I usually always put a &nbsp ; in an empty div, just to be sure or at least only using it as a wrapper (by adding more content inside).